# How To Clean Up A URL From ? to /

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, friendly-url

I need help cleaning up my URLs from this:

http://cocrele.com/service-areas/?state=arkansas&city=amity

to this:

http://cocrele.com/service-areas/arkansas/amity/

I tried a few .htaccess tricks but nothing is sticking using WordPress.

Comment: Related: [WordPress query string to change SEO friendly URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52373847/2943403) and [how to change url like seo friendly in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64852819/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out, this will search for the string in the url, if it contains what you want then you can just set the get parameters based off of that. Very easy fix.

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (strpos($url,'amity') !== false) {
//Do functions, etc. if it contains amity
    $_GET['state'] = 'arkansas';
    $_GET['city'] = 'amity';

} else {
    //Don't do anything
}
```

Comment: Although now, when I create the admin login like domain.com/admin/portal/index.php.<br/>If i create another page like pages.php it redirects still to the index.php????????? <br/>Is there a way to separate the folder hierarchy like If this url has been passed, use separate pages if exits?

<br/>
RewriteEngine On<br/>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)<br/>
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]<br/>
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)<br/>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f<br/>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d<br/>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [NC,QSA,L]<br/>

Answer (score 0):

You would need a custom rewrite rule for that.[check this out](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule).

in your function.php

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%state%', '([^&]+)');
  add_rewrite_tag('%city%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);   


function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^service-area/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=578&state=$matches[1]&city=$matches[2]','top');
  }
  add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

now you can access the same page with URL below: 
http://cocrele.com/service-area/arkansas/amity/

don't forget to reset your permalink after this change to get this to work. just save permalink rules again.

Comment: I tried this but I feel there's more to it then that... I'm using PHP, for instance if $city is empty in URL, show State page and pick a city..

I start here, http://cocrele.com/service-areas/, then go to http://cocrele.com/service-areas/?state=arizona, and then end up here http://cocrele.com/service-areas/?state=arizona&city=bapchule

When you say permalink, I might not know what you mean exactly...

Comment: when you have done with the code, go to Settings -> permalink and save it again, rewrite must use Flush after implementation.

Comment: I did. Sorry, for the delay! If I just change the URL from this: http://cocrele.com/service-area/?state=california&city=arcadia to this: http://cocrele.com/service-area/california/arcadia/ it just redirects back to the home page?

Comment: I have changed please try it again, we need to add page_id which is your case is page_id=578

Comment: So, I re-saved-the functions.php file with the new code above and now it doesn't redirect which is good... But, now it's asking for the state and city again... My guess would be that my PHP needs to change but I'm wondering how to pull data from the DB if I'm not using GET?

But I love the progress!!!!!

Comment: Use add_rewrite_tag() to make WordPress aware of custom querystring variables state and city. Add the following code to the functions.php file, I have updated the answer,If I see your code that would be easier to debug!