# WordPress query string to change SEO friendly URL

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to create SEO friendly URL in the WordPress. Also, I have added a hook in my `functions.php` file as below code but not working.

My URL:

```
http://bddlabs.com/webinar01/?id=pzlyglhbepotwpvbigdatadim_data&storyid=Story_997e9391-71d7-4fac-804b-de891c7aa595
```

I want:

```
http://bddlabs.com/webinar01/pzlyglhbepotwpvbigdatadim_data/Story_997e9391-71d7-4fac-804b-de891c7aa595
```

Is it possible? I am not sure about it. URL query string is coming from the third party, URL query string is coming from the third party, page content render based on query string.

Below code added `landing-page-15.php` it WordPress theme base page template.

```
function fb_change_search_url_rewrite() {
    if ( ! empty( $_GET['storyid'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/webinar01/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 'storyid' ) ) );
        load_template( realpath(__DIR__ . '/..') . '/landing-page-15.php' );        
        exit();
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'fb_change_search_url_rewrite' );
//additional rewrite rule + pagination tested
function rewrite_search_slug() {
    set_query_var('storyid', $_GET['storyid']);
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'find(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?/?',
        'index.php?id=$matches[2]&storyid=$matches[6]',
         'top'      
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_search_slug' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using WordPress builtin permalinks option located in Settings tab.
Set `%category%/%postname%/` so that permalink should work as per your requirements.

When posting new content, select a sub category and put post title the same you want to appear in your permalink.